I don't understand why a simple JoinTable is this slow with Spring boot compared to SQL JOIN TABLE
I have two really simple JPA Spring Entities :  Farm and Coordinates
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "farms")
public class FarmEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "categorie")
    String categorie;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    String nom;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    Coordinates coordinate;

}


// COORDINATES.JAVA

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "coordinates")
public class Coordinates {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    String type;

    @Column(name = "lat")
    String lat;

    @Column(name = "lon")
    String lon;

}



I have about 16k rows in my postgres database,
When im fetching data from JPA Repository -> 200OK 8.34 s 6.56 MB
When im doing a simple JOIN TABLE in sql
SELECT *
FROM farms f
INNER JOIN coordinates c  ON f.id = c.id;




16509 row(s) fetched in 0.037s (0.012s fetch)



Why is there this HUUUGE difference between OneToOne and my JOIN table in SQL ?
Maybe there is a better way to implement this in my entities but i dont find anything even in spring documentations
Thanks for any help or explainations :)

run the JPA created query by hand and find out.

Because you are comparing apples and oranges. You are comparing query execution with query execution + mapping + filling cache + collecting into a list + return the value.

Mapping 16k objects with java should not be that slow, im sure that if i do manual mapping the execution will be 10x faster

I checked hibernates and JPA, i found out that hibernates makes a select for each element instead of getting them all

I found out everything.
Hibernates was creating a select statement for each entity in the request, i was loosing performance in transaction time.
To fetch everything in once, you can use the annotation @EntityGraph
I added this in my repository
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "coordinate")
@Query("SELECT f FROM FarmEntity f INNER JOIN CoordinatesEntity c ON f.id = c.id")
List<FarmEntity> findAllFarms();

From 8s to 300ms 

You can also use @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) on your @OneToOne annotations to do a sub query to get all JOIN entity separately
